# JQuery Autocomplete acts wierd once i publish my website

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using this functionality to fill the **JQuery UI** with *minimum length* set to 2. This code works good when I try to select the list through mouse or through keyboard.

But once I publish my code through my virtual machine it does not work. Neither the minimum length works nor the mouse or keyboard selection works.

Please help me here.

```
 function SPAutoComplete(request, response) {
    //debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Contracts/SearchSpByNumber',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: request,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            var i = 0;
            i++;
            // call autocomplete callback method with results
            response($.map(json, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item.SP_NBR,
                    SPDesc: item.SP_DESC,
                    ID: item.ElementID
                }
            }));
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //alert('error - ' + textStatus);
            console.log('error', textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

  $("#SP1").autocomplete({           
           source: SPAutoComplete,
            minLength: 2,           
            select: function (event, ui) {
                // alert('you have selected ' + ui.item.name + ' ID: ' + ui.item.name);
                $("#SP1").val(ui.item.label);
                $("#SPDesc1").val(ui.item.SPDesc);
                $("#SPDesc1").attr("readonly", true);
                $("#SP1ID").val(ui.item.ID);
                _newDirty = true;
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                debugger;
                if (ui.item != undefined || ui.item != null) {
                    $("#SP1").val(ui.item.label);
                    $("#SPDesc1").val(ui.item.SPDesc);
                    $("#SPDesc1").attr("readonly", true);
                    $("#SP1ID").val(ui.item.ID);
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            },
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                debugger;
                $("#SP1").val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are there any errors displayed in console?

Comment: no i am not getting any error in console. when i try to debug in my local machine i can see debugger hitting the focus poperty but once published focus property is not being hit

Comment: So, Did you check the data returned in the `AJAX` success?

Comment: Yes data is returned back but when i do mouse over on the list, it does not  populate on autocomplete textbox.

Comment: Probably due to `url: 'Contracts/SearchSpByNumber',` Always use `url: '@Url.Action("SearchSpByNumber", "Contracts")';,` so the url is correctly generated.